# string::insert at end of string

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The following two lines do the same thing in Visual Studio 2005:

```
myString.insert(myString.size(),1,myNewChar);
```

and

```
myString.append(1,myNewChar);
```

Is the first one supposed to throw an out_of_range exception or is this the correct behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is correct behavior -- the index you pass is the index of the position *behind* the point of insertion of the new characters, not before. In fact, the C++03 standard specifically says (§21.3.5.4/2):

> Requires `pos1 <= size()` and `pos2 <= str.size()`

(where `pos1` is the index you're passing and `pos2 == npos` in the overload you call) -- note that it's `<=` rather than `<`.

Comment: When confused about indexing always consider the trivial case (string with zero or with one element) and how you'd like to be able to insert in that case.